# Upper limit for Django group membership?

Tags: django, django-guardian

Is there an upper limit(hard or soft) to how many users can be added to a group in Django?

Curious about technical limitations as well as general best practices(eg: don't add more than 10 million users to 1 group or the 4 horsemen of the apocalypse will show up, performance will go down the toilet validating whether a user is a group member, etc..).  Or can I just add every user on the site to 1 group and not worry about it even if the site takes off and every person on planet earth with an internet connection decides to join?

Comment: There is no limit, any query that you run that get's all members of the group with 10 million members will obviously be slow however

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense and during normal use it would only ever be querying whether the user is in the group, not the full group membership.  I may have been over thinking this one, thank you!